# How can I tell if user is moving to next or previous stage of business process flow when OnStageChange event is fired in Dynamic 365 Online?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I'm writing a JS script to intercept and do some additional validations when user moved to the next stage of business process flow in Dynamic 365 Online.

I'm binding my function to [OnStageChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817878.aspx#BKMK_addOnStageChange) event of Dynamic 365, but that event is not only fired when a user moved to next stage but also when he moved back to previous stage as well.

Is the any way to tell if the user is moving to the next or the previous stage?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to update your code for the `OnStageChange` to `getEventArgs`, this will allow you to see if the `getDirection` was 'next' or 'previous.'

Without seeing your code, I can't provide specific implementation advice, but this answers your question.

Below is the link for further understanding how to handle `OnStageChange' events:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334481.aspx#BKMK_OnStageChange

Comment: Thank you very much. I did check that doc, I can't believe that I missed the part about getEventArgs.

Comment: @tsukumogami if this is the correct answer, please mark it so that people with this problem in the future are able to find a resolution. You're not the first to encounter this problem, and won't be the last! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @OneNeptune, I managed to solved my problem as follow.

```
const NEXT_STAGE_OPTION = "Next"

function onAccountFormLoad (context) {
    context.getFormContext().data.process.addOnStageChange(checkMoveStage);
}

function checkMoveStage(context) {
    var targetStageName = context.getFormContext().data.process.getActiveStage().getName();
    var direction = context.getEventArgs().getDirection();
    console.log("Move to " + direction + " stage:" + targetStageName);

    if (direction === NEXT_STAGE_OPTION) {
        // Perform necessary validation when moving to next stage.
    }
}
```

Function onFormLoad is added to onLoad event of form, with "Pass execution context as first parameter" option checked.